# Can I add more nodes to a Cloud Spanner Instance?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have created a Cloud Spanner Instance for evaluation and staging purposes.  I think I am ready to move on and make it a production-ready database.  Is there a way for me to add more nodes to the Instance, without having to create a totally new Instance and clone all my data over to it?

Answer (score 1):

From the Instance Details page, in the right pane, there are three options at the top: Create Database, Edit Instance, Delete Instance.  Go to Edit Instance.
From here, you can change the name of the Instance, or the number of nodes.  Change the number of nodes and you will see an estimated cost per hour.  If you are happy with your changes, hit Save.

You can also reduce the number of nodes, but for redundancy and availability purposes, Spanner Team recommends a minimum of three nodes for a production environment.